# Game paths in android to show levels in game like CandyCrush

Tags: android, android-activity, andengine, game-engine

I am creating an Android app where i need to show a maps like screen in Candycrush,can any one please suggest me how to create path in android.

Comment: Completely off topic.

Comment: Please show us what you tried so far so we can help you with a problems. But this site is not to help with general ideas, especially when a question is not clear

Answer (score 1):

I would propose the logic as below, but not the detailed code for your consideration.

In another words, you wanted to show an extra-large map (say, 4x screen-height, 1x screen-width), draggable, right?

The key-pointis, to divid it into 4 x pics of sceen-size.(or more) Then, your mobile can handle properly.
Initial coordinations on scene:

pic1 - location 0,0

pic2 - location 0,heightx1

pic3 - location 0,heightx2

pic4 - location 0,heightx3

On CreateScene, put pic1,pic2 on scene. (or load pic3 & 4 if no memory concern)

Attach touchlistener to pic1, pic2 (and 3,4) (make them into movable sprites)

When Action_down, record X,Y coordinations

When Action_move, set current posiion as pic position (and update corresponding X,Y for other pics)

See if this fit for you?